# Java applets in a browser on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, safari, java, plugins, oracle

Is it possible to run a Java applet in any browser in MacOS 10.9.2? Chrome does not work with Java applets because it's a 32 bit app and the Java plugin is 64 bit only. Firefox and Safari both should be able to use Oracle's Java plugin, but it does not seem to work.

The official [java.com](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en) download from Oracle is "Version 7 Update 55". It installs via a .pkg installer but the plugin still does not work in Safari or Firefox. I did verify that `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` exists, but it is not showing up in Safaris' list of plugins.

Oracle's installer adds a new "Java" system preference, with a security tab with a checkbox "Enable Java content in the browser". This is checked off. I check it on, click "Apply", and am prompted for my password. Then the dialog flashes and the box remains checked off. The plugin still does not work. I do note my console has a log line `FAILURE: Job com.oracle.java.deployment.Helper is not loaded in launchd.` There is an [unresolved bug against OpenJDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029309) for this problem that may be why it's not working. It is several months old.

Some searching frequently turns up advice to [re-enable Java 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5559). I really do not want to do this, but I am interested to know if it works in Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

I´m using OSX 10.9.2 and Java (version 7 update 55) with Firefox (Nightly) and latest Safari and it works. It is right, that Java will not be shown in Safari extensions but I could find it under Firefox plugins.

I suggest that you [uninstall Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml), check that everything will be wiped off and reinstall Java. Normally Java will be enabled in system settings by default.

Update: If these doesn´t help please create another user and logon into a fresh user profile. Do you´ve got the same bug in Java system preferences?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation it does work for you. I've tried reinstalling and no joy. Doesn't show up in Firefox or Safari plugs, despite clearly being in the Internet Plug-Ins directory.

Does your Java system preferences tool show the same bug I'm reporting above?

Comment: No, I could use the java system preferences normal. But I´ve added a hint to my answer that´s maybe a try worth.